# How to open another app from React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

On my React Native Expo project, there is a button that will open WhatsApp with a pre-fill message box. It works fine when I test it on Expo Go but it doesn't work when I installed it with APK on my android. It doesn't recognized that I already installed WhatsApp. This are the urls that I tried:
`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phoneNumber}&text=${message}`, `whatsapp://send?text=${message}&phone=${phoneNumber}`, `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phoneNumber}&text=${message}`. I saw some asked similar question. Only one had an answer but the solution is similar to mine and it didn't resolve the problem.

```
const whatsApp = () => {
        const phoneNumber = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? '601234567891' : '+601234567891';
        const message = `My Message.`;
        const url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phoneNumber}&text=${message}`;
        Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
            if (!supported) {
                return Alert.alert(
                    'Error',
                    'WhatsApp is not installed on this device. Please install WhatsApp and try again.'
                );
            }
            return Linking.openURL(url);
        }).catch(() =>
            Alert.alert(
                'Error',
                'An error occurred while trying to open WhatsApp. Please try again later.'
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it like this to send a specific message to a specific number

```
Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?text=YOUR_MESSAGE&phone=THE_PHONE_NUMBER')
```